# How can I fill a dataframe on specific column names of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have constructed a pretty basic dataframe where the column names are years:

```
import pandas as pd
column_names = [x for x in range(2000,2005)]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
```

Which of course gives me a dataframe where the column names are years and currently has no entries.

```
2000    2001    2002    2003    2004
```

I also have a different dataframe where one column has specific dates and the second column has the corresponding year. I call this dataframe set0 because I will continously add more sets which are then numbered (set1,set2,etc.).

```
data = {'Date': ['2001-06-08', '2002-05-23', '2002-05-24', '2003-06-23'],
        'Year': [2001, 2002, 2002, 2003]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

Date    Year
0   2001-06-08  2001
1   2002-05-23  2002
2   2002-05-24  2002
3   2003-06-23  2003
```

Now what I want to do is to create something like this: It takes the first dataframe, adds a first column which has a name of a certain dataset, in this case set0. I will then group this dataset by years and if I have an entry for a year I can create this:

```
set_name 2000   2001    2002    2003    2004
set0        0      1       2       1       0
```

I have found nothing similar on the web. I have done the grouping but then wasn't able to add the entries in the corresponding columns. Any help or hint is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this answer your question ?

```py
import pandas as pd

column_names = [x for x in range(2000, 2005)]

df = pd.DataFrame(index=column_names)

data = {
    'Date': ['2001-06-08', '2002-05-23', '2002-05-24', '2003-06-23'],
    'Year': [2001, 2002, 2002, 2003]
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2_grouped = df2.groupby('Year').count()['Date']

df['set0'] = df2_grouped
# Pandas version 1.5+
df = df.fillna(0).reset_index(names='set_name').pivot_table(columns='set_name')
# All versions : 
df = df.fillna(0).reset_index().rename(columns={
    'index': 'set_name'
}).pivot_table(columns='set_name')


print(df)
```

Result :

```
set_name  2000  2001  2002  2003  2004
set0       0.0   1.0   2.0   1.0   0.0
```

Comment: Hi and thank you very very much. Your solution looks so easy :-) I have tried to compile this but I get an error regarding rest_index(names= ...
It says: reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'names'
What was the intention to do that? Thank you for clarification :-)

Comment: Ah yes it's a new keyword of pandas 1.5 for reset_index() (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html). It allows to rename directly the reset index with the entered name ;)

Comment: I think this is due to a different Pandas-Version. I will try to update it since I am on a PC from work. Is there a workaround maybe?

Comment: Yes only working, with pandas 1.5+. Check my correction if you want, I added sth for all versions